# Extending Objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to extend the `Nokohiri::XML::Node` object into my own unique object with custom behaviors (methods).

I have the following object:

```
class RDFNode < Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def get_tag
    self.at_xpath("Path/to/tag")
  end
end
```

and the Node Factory:

```
class RDFNodeFactory
  @doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse('rdf_file.xml')

  def self.get_node(id)
    @doc.xpath_at("Path/to/rdf/node[@id=#{id}]")
  end
end
```

My question is about best Ruby practices and basic OOP in Ruby.

How can I get `RDFNodeFactory.get_node("someid")` to return an `RDFNode` instead of a `Nokogiri::XML::Node`? I used to use type casting in Java but we don't have that in Ruby.

Should I just modify `Nokogiri::XML::Node` class instead of extending it to a custom class? What is a more acceptable practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of extending the `Nokogiri::XML::Node` class just to add one method, you should move the get_tag method and add it to the already existing `Nokogiri::XML::Node` using the concept of [Open Classes.](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html) This would look like:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def get_tag
    self.at_xpath("Path/to/tag")
  end
end
```

This is completely fine in terms of Ruby Standards, just be sure there aren't any side affects when adding this method to Nokogiri::XML::Node, such as get_tag already exists.

With regards to open class(under the assumption that there are no current conflicts) vs inheriting 3rd party libraries:

This is a valid fear, this is why you have to be very careful when you utilize open classes and updating 3rd party libraries. However if you think of it, if a library changes their code in such a way that it messes up your code... This will happen both when you use open classes or inherit from their code. When it all boils down, you have a dependency, and you must be careful no matter what.

Comment: Yes, and I love Open Classes but they scare me sometimes. It seems like, to me, that you really risk destroying modularity when you just add methods willy nilly to a class belonging to a separately maintained gem. Nokogiri may be updated and then my gem/app is broken.

Is this a legitimate fear or am I being paranoid?

Comment: Adding tests that reflect your changes are important to avoid problems when opening classes, that way if a new version of a gem breaks your change you'll know it.

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods tied to object, not class, so there is no way to "cast" object to another class. But in ruby you can add methods to existing class:

```
class Nokogiri::XML::Node
  def get_tag
    self.at_xpath("Path/to/tag")
  end
end
```

Or even add method to single object:

```
def @doc.get_tag
  self.at_xpath("Path/to/tag")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A (sort of) solution I have is containment

```
class RDFNode
  attr_reader :node
  def initialize(node)
    @node = node
  end

  def get_tag(id)
    node.at_xpath("Path/to/tag")
  end
end
```

Now I have preserved modularity but lost all the awesomeness of inheritance! Not perfect but it's a start. Perhaps there is some way improve on this (extend RDFNode with Nokogiri::XML::Node and make self = node for Nokogiri methods)?